# new to java - need to understand how an object can receive 2 different return values

Tags: java, android, android-volley

if we look at the following code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

notice how both getInstance() and getImageLoader() are begin called, each one is returning something. How can this one object, imageLoader receive 2 different objects? Or am I misunderstanding everything... I a bit confused

here is what getInstance looks like:

```
public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
```

Here is what getImageLoader looks like:

```
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {


    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }


    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

is a shortcut form for:

```
AppController appController = AppController.getInstance();
ImageLoader imageLoader = appController.getImageLoader();
```

In this case, the author does not need access to the `AppController` instance, only to the `ImageLoader` instance that it provides.  When a method returns an object, that object does not have to be assigned to a variable before it can be used.  In this case, the only reason to get the AppController instance is to call `getImageLoader()` on it.

You can chain methods in a strong-typed language like Java quite easily, because you always know the return value of a method.  You can do things like:

```
Integer value = SomeClass.someMethod().someOtherMethod().someThirdMethod();
```

In this case, `SomeClass` has a method called `someMethod` that returns an instance of some class.  This instance has a method `someOtherMethod` that returns an instance of some second class.  This second class has a method `someThirdMethod` which returns an Integer.

You don't have to have left-hand-side assignment if you are not going to need the object beyond the scope of the current call.

Answer (score 4):

> notice how both getInstance() and getImageLoader() are begin called,
>   each one is returning something. How can this one object, imageLoader
>   receive 2 different objects?

No, this line only returns an `ImageLoader`. It is equivalent to :

```
AppController tmp    = AppController.getInstance(); // temporary intermediate variable
ImageLoader   loader = tmp.getImageLoader();        // final result
```

You are simply chaining the method calls to prevent yourself from storing an intermediate variable and save one line of code if tmp is not reused later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are misunderstanding it.

The object `imageLoader` only receives the return value from `getImageLoader()`, which is (not surprisingly) an `ImageLoader`.

`getImageLoader()` is called from the return value of `getInstance()`, which is an `AppController`.

In summary:
The method `getInstance()` returns an `AppController` from which you call `getImageLoader()` which is then saved in the `imageLoader` variable.